# best practice for sharing data between users

Tags: partitioning, users, home-directory, sharing

I'm new to ubuntu 
and i've partitioned disk as follows

```
/      100G
swap   30g -- i need to run virtuals
/home  500g
```

and that structure after searching

the problem I face is where to put files for all users

Comment: Just create a folder in the `/home` directory for AllUsers and make it shared by following the linked question.